# How are all files and directories created as root:root in smb mount ( RHEL)?

Tags: linux, rhel, samba, smb

We have smb mount point in one of our RHEL server. By logging as normal user, any file or directory created by the user is shown as root:root. What configuration has been made to force user and group shown as root:root always ? I have checked /etc/samba/smb.conf, no configuration has been found. And also all file and directory getting created by normal user has full 777 permission. Appreciate any quickest help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The userid/gid "owning" a particular mounted SMB partition are determined by its mounting configuration.

You may want to check this Q&A: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68079/mount-cifs-network-drive-write-permissions-and-chown